# Historical milestones in experimental "verification" that light is a electromagnetic phenomenum

Tags: physics, electromagnetism

This is a follow up question to [How did Maxwell conclude that light is an electromagnetic wave?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/3120/2380) where the arguments of Maxwell were explained why he considered light as an electromagnetic wave.

What was the furhter milestones towards more and more direct and clearer experimental tests of the electric and magnetic properties of light waves?

I am not sure if the following experiment would consider as such a milestone because it demonstrated the magnetic property of light rather directly: http://physics.aps.org/story/v26/st13

Comment: In the answers to your previous question Faraday's experiments were mentioned. Another milestone was Herz's experiment. What else are you asking about? Invention of radio? But I would not call this a "milestone". After Herz experiments the fact was clear.

Comment: With Hertz you know that electromagnetic waves can be produced. But not that light "is" an electromagnetic wave.  With Faraday and Kerr effects you know that it has to do somethin with electricity and magnetism. But up to now there are no direct experiments which show clearly that light has an effect on charged bodies or magnetic ones.

Comment: Nevertheless nobody doubted this after Hertz. By the principle that "if it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck and looks like a duck, then it probably is a duck" :-)